# FileNotFoundException and file path

Tags: c#, .net, filenotfoundexception

Exception:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Program%20Files\Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%209.0\Common7\IDE\Projects\SourceCode_TradeProcessor_branch\BIN\FxGate\LoaderService\Plugins\FixExchangeProvider\FixExchangeProvider.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

code:

```
parserPlugin = Assembly.LoadFrom(_transport.Path);
```

The filepath exists. Is it because of path format or what?

Answer (score 4):

"...or one of its dependencies". Check if the dll's your assembly references are in the same folder.

Comment: can you pls recommend the tool for that

Comment: Reflector will do that, and a whole bunch more besides, otherwise ndepends, there are others.

Comment: Reflector Analyzer said nothing

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
parserPlugin = Assembly.LoadFrom(new Uri(_transport.Path).LocalPath);
```

would work better?

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be permissions, if the user the program's running under doesn't even have permission to see what's in the folder it'll have to assume the file's not there.